# MonoGame - Get grid cell position where the cursor is in a world that is relative to a matrix

Tags: c#, debugging, console, monogame

I am just coding my game and I stuck with getting the cell position.
I need to get cell position where the cursor is, and everything is drawing relative to camera matrix.

I've tried many things - doing many stuff with Vector2 positions, matrix itself, and I got nowhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Code that tries to get grid cell position:

```cs
                    // Getting view matrix
                    var viewMatrix = cam.GetTransform();
                    Vector2 worldPosition = Vector2.Transform(mouse.Position.ToVector2(), Matrix.Invert(viewMatrix));

                    // Getting the grid cell position where cursor is
                    int width = 80;
                    int height = 80;
                    int size = 64;

                    for (int forX = 0; forX < width; forX++)
                    {
                        for (int forY = 0; forY < height; forY++)
                        {
                            int mouseXmin = (size * forX) + 1;
                            int mouseXmax = mouseXmin + 63;
                            int mouseYmin = (size * forY) + 1;
                            int mouseYmax = mouseYmin + 63;

                            Vector2 minVector = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(mouseXmin, mouseYmin), Matrix.Invert(viewMatrix));
                            Vector2 maxVector = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(mouseXmax, mouseYmax), Matrix.Invert(viewMatrix));

                            if (worldPosition.X > minVector.X && worldPosition.X < maxVector.X
                                && worldPosition.Y > minVector.Y && worldPosition.Y < maxVector.Y)
                            {
                                // Some debug stuff, this is where I got that it does not work beacuse of matrix magic
                                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied,
                                       null, null, null, null, viewMatrix);
                                debugRectangle = new Rectangle((int)minVector.X, (int)minVector.Y, (int)maxVector.X, (int)maxVector.Y);
                                spriteBatch.End();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Drawing code:

```cs
            // Getting view matrix
            var viewMatrix = cam.GetTransform();

            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied,
                                       null, null, null, null, viewMatrix);

            // Drawing grid
            for (float x = 0; x < 80; x++)
            {
                int length = 64 * 79;
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle((int)(64 * x), 0, 1, length);
                spriteBatch.Draw(px, rectangle, Color.White);
            }

            for (float y = 0; y < 80; y++)
            {
                int length = 64 * 79;
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, (int)(64 * y), length, 1);
                spriteBatch.Draw(px, rectangle, Color.White);
            }

            // Drawing blocks
            for (int forX = 0; forX < 80; forX++)
            {
                for (int forY = 0; forY < 80; forY++)
                {
                    Block block = blocks[forX, forY];
                    if (block == null) continue;
                    int x = (64 * forX) + (1 * (forX + 1));
                    int y = (64 * forY) + (1 * (forX + 1));
                    switch (block.type)
                    {
                        case Block.BlockType.AND:
                            spriteBatch.Draw(and, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
                            break;
                        case Block.BlockType.NAND:
                            spriteBatch.Draw(nand, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
                            break;
                        case Block.BlockType.NOR:
                            spriteBatch.Draw(nor, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
                            break;
                        case Block.BlockType.NOT:
                            spriteBatch.Draw(not, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
                            break;
                        case Block.BlockType.NXOR:
                            spriteBatch.Draw(nxor, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
                            break;
                        case Block.BlockType.OR:
                            spriteBatch.Draw(or, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
                            break;
                        case Block.BlockType.WIRE:
                            DrawRectangle(new Rectangle(x + 15, y + 15, 35, 35), Color.Black);
                            if (block.active) DrawFilledRectangle(new Rectangle(x + 17, y + 17, 31, 31), Color.Green);
                            else DrawFilledRectangle(new Rectangle(x + 17, y + 17, 33, 33), Color.Red);
                            break;
                        case Block.BlockType.XOR:
                            spriteBatch.Draw(xor, new Vector2(x, y), Color.White);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            spriteBatch.End();
```

Camera:

```cs
    public class Camera
    {
        public Camera()
        {
            Zoom = 1;
            Position = Vector2.Zero;
            Rotation = 0;
            Origin = Vector2.Zero;
            Position = Vector2.Zero;
        }

        public float Zoom { get; set; }
        public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
        public float Rotation { get; set; }
        public Vector2 Origin { get; set; }

        public void Move(Vector2 direction)
        {
            Position += direction;
        }

        public Matrix GetTransform()
        {
            var translationMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Position.X, Position.Y, 0));
            var rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation);
            var scaleMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 1));
            var originMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Origin.X, Origin.Y, 0));

            return translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * scaleMatrix * originMatrix;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Vector2 mouseToWorldPosition = Vector2.Transform(mousePosition, Matrix.Invert(Camera.TransformMatrix));
```

In camera:

```
public Matrix TransformMatrix
    {
        get
        {
            return Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-Position.X, -Position.Y, 0)) *
                Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
                Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom) *
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(Bounds.Width * 0.5f, Bounds.Height * 0.5f, 0));
        }
    }
```